# CAR and CDR in LISP

Tags: lisp, clisp

Suppose there's a LISP list L described by `((A B) (C))`

How to print the result of `(CAR L)` and `(CDR L)`?

(in clisp interpreter)

I am able to print these simple statements like *(CAR `(A B C))* which gives *A*. But how do I define the list and CAR it at the same time?

Comment: "Define and `car` it at the same time" - What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Common Lisp you can print a value using, well, the `print` procedure:

```
(defvar L '((A B) (C)))

(print (car L)) ; same as (print (car '((A B) (C))))
=> '(A B)

(print (cdr L)) ; same as (print (cdr '((A B) (C))))
=> '((C))
```

Comment: It's giving me the error as - 
    CAR: 1 is not a list
    The following restarts are available....

Comment: You probably made a typo when writing it, just copy paste the above code, I assure you that _it works_.

Comment: Hey, but when I try to execute it in a .lisp file, it says *** - EVAL: undefined function DEFINE. What did I do wrong now?